# How to install the mongodb-plugin for grafana using a docker container?

Tags: mongodb, docker, grafana

I would like to use Grafana for my MongoDB for visualisation. I found a solution how to add the mongoDB-plugin into a Linux-system. But how can I add this plugin via docker?

Plugin: https://github.com/JamesOsgood/mongodb-grafana

Comment: like that? https://hub.docker.com/r/maxbr/mongodb-grafana

Answer (score 0):

you can use this image which includes grafana and the mongodb plugin :
https://github.com/ajeje93/grafana-mongodb-docker

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34336979)